# Changing Saturation based on the amount of objects placed in game - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a block-placing game with a 2d building system and I am trying to modify the post-processing saturation based on the amount of blocks place, starting at -100 saturation (grayscale) and eventually ending at 0 (full color). The more blocks the player places, the more colorful the game/world becomes.

I have managed to access the total blocks placed from another object but I am stuck on how to properly change the saturation. The `satu` value is changing in the inspector and I have checked the `Override State` box but it is not affecting the post-processing saturation. I slide the saturation slider in game mode and the saturation changes, but there is a disconnect between this and the `satu` value that changes:

```
// Referecning the script where blockTotal is found    
BuildSystem buildSys;
    
// Total blocks in game, this already increases with every block ( ++ done in BuildSystem script)
[SerializeField] int blockTotal;

// Saturation    
public FloatParameter satu;

//Variable to control saturation sensitivity to each block placed
[SerializeField] float colorMultiplier = 1f;

private ColorGrading colorGrading;

public GameObject gameManager;

void Start() 
    {            
        buildSys = gameManager.GetComponent<BuildSystem>();
        colorGrading = GetComponent<ColorGrading>();
        
        satu = colorGrading.saturation;
    }

void Update() 
    {
        blockTotal = buildSys.blockTotal;
        satu.value = blockTotal * colorMultiplier;
    }
```

I am aware that the `satu.value = blockTotal * colorMultiplier` equation is going to be more complex since saturation starts at -100, but I am currently working with starting at 0 and ending at 100 just to test if the system works, which it doesn't yet. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of `satu.value` when you should be setting `colorGrading.saturation.value`.